# Receiving Custom Data (Bool, Int) from Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I'm sending a custom **FCM** message (more than just a title and a body) to my iOS app through curl as follows.

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=myServerKey" \
--Header "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
-d @- << EOF
{
  "to": "my device token",
    "data": {
        "urlFlag": true,
        "category": "Electric",
        "messageId": 1238884523
    },
    "notification": {
        "title": "Test"
        "body": "What do you want?"
    }
}
EOF
```

And I receive the push message through the `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` method in `AppDelegate` as follows.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        /* Firebase Cloud Messaging */
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
            } else if let token = token {
                if self.showFirebaseToken {
                    print("Remote FCM registration token: \(token)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        return true
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
                
        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any], let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String: Any] {
            if let title = alert["title"] as? String, let body = alert["body"] as? String {
                print("title: \(title) body: \(body)") // good
            }
        }
        
        if let urlFlag = userInfo["urlFlag"] as? Bool {
            print("Flag: \(urlFlag)") // no good
        }
        if let category = userInfo["category"] as? String {
            print("category: \(category)") // good
        }
        if let messageId = userInfo["messageId"] as? Int {
            print("ID: \(messageId)") // no good
        }
    }
}
```

The app does receive the title and the body with no problem.  If the custom dataset contains a boolean type, a string type, a number type, the app will only receive the `String` one only.  How can I have my app receive a boolean type and a number type?  Thanks.

**EDIT**

`userInfo` returns the following.

```
[AnyHashable("google.c.fid"): cgthRgMJPEkaidXXhrXuqv, AnyHashable("urlFlag"): true, AnyHashable("messageId"): 1238884523, AnyHashable("aps"): {

    alert =     {

        body = "What do you want?";

        title = Test;

    };

}, AnyHashable("google.c.sender.id"): 1073343011223, AnyHashable("category"): Electric, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1627387811171401]
```

Comment: If you print `userInfo`, what's the output exactly?

Comment: @Larme Thank you for your question.  I've written an answer to your question above.

Comment: `if let urlFlag = userInfo["urlFlag"] { print("Flag without cast: \(urlFlag)") }` works, no? So the cast is wrong?

Comment: `if let urlFlag = userInfo["urlFlag"] { print("Flag without cast: \(urlFlag)") }` works, no? So the cast is wrong? Try: `print(type(of: userInfo["urlFlag"]!))`, or with `urlFlag` unwrapped just before.

Comment: @Larme Yes.  Thanks.  That does it.  Are you going to sumit that as a solution?  Or should I close the topic?

Comment: You got a print until know, but it's unclear how to use it yet. `print(type(of: userInfo["urlFlag"]!))` output might help though. Same for the other one causing issue.

Comment: @Larme urlFlag's type returns as `NSTaggedPointerString`, `__NSCFString` for messageId.

Comment: So it means, they are `String`, not `Bool` nor `Int`, that's why the `as? Bool` and `as? Int` fail...

Comment: @Larme That does mean I cannot send them as Bool, Int, then?  Just send them as strings, instead, probably?

Comment: I don't know if it's an issue or a rule with FirebaseMessagingCloud that convert the value to String or not... Might need a check on their documentation... But for now: `if let urlFlagStr = userInfo["urlFlag"] as? String { let urlFlagBool = (urlFlagStr == "true") }` might do the trick...

Comment: @Larme I think the following works. if let bool = (urlFlag as? NSString)?.boolValue {print("Bool: \(bool)")}